# Problema al cargar archivo .xls (JSP)

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-poi

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación desarrollada en JSP que corre en jBoss, especificamente estoy trabajando en un módulo donde al darle click a un botón, él redirige la acción a un Servlet el cual busca y carga un archivo .xls el cual posteriormente se quiere procesar.

Parte del JSP donde está el botón:

```
            <div class="offset-2 col-sm-5 text-center">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <h3 class="panel-heading">1. Cargar Tasas: </h3>
                    <form action="./CargaTasasServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><button class="btn btn-secondary panel-body" name="cargaTasas" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Cargar</button></form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CargaTasasServlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    fileStorePath = "\\\\wdepteso1d\\Apps\\SIDETWEB\\"; 

    file = new File(fileStorePath+"Tasas.xls");

    //Carga de archivo Excel.       
        ExcelFileReader excelFileReader;
        excelFileReader= new ExcelFileReader();
        JSONArray array = excelFileReader.readExcel(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

ExcelFileReader.java:

```
package co.gov.banrep.dte.logic.xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class ExcelFileReader {

    public static JSONArray readExcel (String filePath)
    {       
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        try {
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);


            Sheet sheet= workbook.cloneSheet(0); //Lee la primera página del excel
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

            // Se procede a leer la fila y la celda
            ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
            int i = 0;
            for(Row row: sheet){
                JSONObject value = new JSONObject();
                int j = 0;
                for(Cell cell: row){
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        String cell_value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        keys.add(cell_value);
                    }
                    else{
                        String cell_value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        value.put(keys.get(j), cell_value); 
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if(!value.isEmpty())
                {
                    array.add(value);
                }
                i++;
            }
            workbook.close();
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return array;
    }   
}
```

Lo curioso es que ya había logrado que funcionara correctamente, es decir, el archivo era leído y convertido a JSON exitosamente. Pero de un momento a otro me dejó de funcionar, y empezó a generarme esta traza de errores:

```
09:29:15,359 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sidetweb].[co.gov.banrep.dte.logic.xml.CargaTasasServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() para servlet co.gov.banrep.dte.logic.xml.CargaTasasServlet lanzó excepción: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException from [Module "deployment.sidetweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at co.gov.banrep.dte.logic.xml.CargaTasasServlet.doPost(CargaTasasServlet.java:97) [classes:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
```

Según veo se lanza la exepción: org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException

La cual se lanza si el archivo está encriptado, pero es un archivo común y corriente. Además, como comentaba anteriormente el código ya funcionaba.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El error es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException
```

Es decir, la clase `org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException` no es encontrada (es una dependencia de tu código). Eso no significa obligatoriamente que se fuese a lanzar, pero alguna dependencia parece estar fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo que en las librerias tengo los siguientes .jar:

- poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
- poi-3.15.jar

Ambos contienen una paquete llamado `org.apache.poi` la diferencia entre ellos es que el segundo es el que contiene el "EncryptedDocumentException".

¿Estos paquetes duplicados son los que generan el problema? Si es así, ¿cómo podría evitar u omitir el paquete poi-ooxml-3.15.jar?

Comment: Por favor, no utilices las respuestas para realizar preguntas.

Comment: Haz creado otra cuenta por error? tuviste algun problema para acceder a la anterior? podrias comunicarte conmigo y decirme si es asi?

Comment: Primero publiqué el problema como invitado, e inmediatamente creé la cuenta con el mismo correo. Como se puede notar quedaron como cuentas distintas, pero ambas usan el mismo correo. @gbianchi

Comment: Perfecto. Ahora pido que te las unan.

Comment: Una vez que las unan, podras modificar la pregunta con esta informacion de ser necesario, o crear otra pregunta, segun corresponda.